# How to make another key instead of replacing it in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, discord.js

I am trying to add "ProductName":"TRUE/FALSE" to my database, but when I add another (using javascript), it just removes the previous one, and adds the new one.
Here is my code:

```
database.ref(`product-whitelist`).child(Id).set({
    [productname]: "TRUE"
});
```

But whenever this is run again, and "productname" has changed, it removes the previous one that was made.

If anyone knows how I can fix this, please let me know!

Comment: How are you creating the product Id?

Comment: The Id is just a users discord id (its using discord to get their products)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the `update()` method:

```
database.ref(`product-whitelist`).child(Id).update({
    [productname]: "TRUE"
});
```

This will write the value of `[productname]` and leave other properties under `child(Id)` untouched.

---

The above code is equivalent to:

```
database.ref(`product-whitelist`).child(Id).child(productname).set("TRUE");
```

But this approach can only write one property. By using `update` you can set some properties, while leave others untouched.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will try this tomorrow. Also as a side note, I think I have tried the update method already, but I will still try it incase I somehow did it wrong.

Comment: Hi, I just tried it - It is still deleting the other keys with their values when one is added.
Also, if it changes anything, [productname] connects to a variable.

Comment: I just tried using it with another key ,https://gyazo.com/638876d0221bfeeb51aed57b5cc179f1
It works, so I'm gonna try and find out why it is still removing itself for that particular key.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
database.ref(`product-whitelist\`+Id).child(productname).set({
    [productname]: "TRUE"
});
```

Comment: Hi, I've already tried this way, still resulted in the same issue. Thanks for your reply though!

Comment: Is your productname similar for every entry?

Comment: No, it is linked to a variable.